# Wpf Priority of EventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf, eventargs

When I pushed slider which children of Grid I want to childrens eventargs should trigger before Grid.I want to e.handled true after my grids children triggered. How do I do this. Thanks for interest.

Here is my grids mousedown

```
public void myd(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
                {

            if (sender as Label != null)
            {
                if (typeof(DashBoardGrid).IsAssignableFrom(Operations.FindParent<Grid>(Operations.FindParent<Grid>(sender as Label)).GetType()))
                {
                    var sender3 = Operations.FindParent<Grid>(Operations.FindParent<Grid>(sender as Label)) as DashBoardGrid;
                    foreach (var item in DashBoardItems)
                    {
                        item.IsSelected = Visibility.Hidden;
                    }
                    sender3.IsSelected = Visibility.Visible;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            else if (sender as Viewbox != null)
            {
                if (typeof(DashBoardGrid).IsAssignableFrom(Operations.FindParent<Grid>(sender as Viewbox).GetType()))
                {
                    var sender3 = Operations.FindParent<Grid>(sender as Viewbox) as DashBoardGrid;
                    foreach (var item in DashBoardItems)
                    {
                        item.IsSelected = Visibility.Hidden;
                    }
                    sender3.IsSelected = Visibility.Visible;
                    //e.Handled = true;
                }
            }


            else if (sender as Grid != null)
                    {
                        if (typeof(DashBoardGrid).IsAssignableFrom(Operations.FindParent<Grid>(sender as Grid).GetType()))
                        {
                            var sender3 = Operations.FindParent<Grid>(sender as Grid) as DashBoardGrid;
                            foreach (var item in DashBoardItems)
                            {
                                item.IsSelected = Visibility.Hidden;
                            }
                            sender3.IsSelected = Visibility.Visible;
                            e.Handled = true;
                        }
                    }
```

This is my ChildrenControls mouse down

```
  private void RotaryControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_ellipseOuterDial.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(_ellipseOuterDial)) == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            PositionMarkerFromControlPosition(e.GetPosition(_ellipseOuterDial));

            _ellipseOuterDial.CaptureMouse();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to understand what you're asking about. Please reword or rewrite your question.

Comment: I have a Viewbox and one control which named rotary control is  inside my Viewbox. My Viewbox have a mousedown event which make panel.settop and panel.setleft and my rotarycontrol have mousedown event which make dial efect to my slider but viewbox 's event triggers before rotarycontrol ı want to rotary control mousedown must trigger before.